# GCC C compiler (gcc -Wall -o foo.c foo.c )

Tags: c, gcc

When I type to my terminal:

```
gcc -Wall -o foo.c foo.c
```

After that `foo.c` is deleted. There is no reason to type this but does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: When I type that, it writes the compiled code inside `foo.c`.

Comment: When you say 'deleted', do you mean 'replaced with the executable code for the program'?  There's a difference — in one case, the file `foo.c` no longer exists; in the other, the file exists but your source code doesn't.  I assume it is 'replaced; the source code has gone'.  It's basically doing what you told it to do — compile the input `foo.c` and write the program to the file `foo.c`.

Comment: The obvious answer is that it's clobbering `foo.c` because you told it to. But with gcc 7.5.0 and 6.3.0 (what version are you using?) I get `gcc: fatal error: input file ‘foo.c’ is the same as output file` `compilation terminated.` and it *doesn't* clobber `foo.c`. Is that the *exact* (copy-and-pasted) command you ran? (In the absence of that check, I'd expect it to write the executable to `foo.c`, replacing your source file -- or possibly opening `foo.c` for output might interfere with compilation.)

Comment: Interestingly, clang (unlike gcc) doesn't perform this check. It successfully writes the executable to `foo.c`. (clang versions 6.0.0 and 9.0.0.)

Answer (score 4):

`-o foo.c` says to write the output to `foo.c`.

You probably mean `-o foo` to ensure you don't overwrite your source.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the behaviour you describe only in clang<sup>1</sup> and only if the code in `bla.c` fails during the linking stage<sup>2</sup>. In those circumstances the deletion probably happens for the following reason:

The compiler creates the final file to hold the final executable as soon as linking starts, but when linking fails the file is deleted. So the original `bla.c` disappears because it is starting to be overwritten by the executable file, but that file is also deleted because linking failed and the executable is never successfully created. So you end up with neither file.

---

<sup>1</sup> GCC just plain refuses to have an output file with the same name as a source file, but it's possible older versions behaved as you describe.

<sup>2</sup> If it does compile, `bla.c` is replaced with an executable.

Comment: Also there are many terminals in which typing `gcc` runs `clang`. Thanks, Apple!